# Persistent Context scope in jpa

Tags: jpa, orm

I'm designing a web application. In the web application the transaction is specific to a thread since for each new request a new thread is created by the thread pool.

In hibernate for sharing the sessions between the application context is managed by threadlocal session context. I'm new to JPA, I'm injecting the persistent context in the application using @PersistentContext. Is it local to thread?

Answer (score 2):

No, the JPA `EntityManager` is not thread-local. It is also not thread-safe, so you should not share an instance between threads.

Usually, it is not an issue, since the `EntityManager` is not passed around in method calls. Beans rely on the container to inject the appropriate `EntityManager`.